# jQuery Slider Min Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, uislider

I know there is a min value in jquery's slider. However, is there a way I can make the slider handle stop moving under some value? Is there any variable I can change to make this happen?

**Note:** My Slider is vertical 

Basically, if the minimum is 20, I don't want the slider handle going under 20.

Comment: you've gotta add code and a lot more information here to get an answer - like are you using a plugin or what code are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can check it in `slide` functionality as below:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/50b8mwc7/1/)**

```
$(function() {
      $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: false,
            value:20,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                 if (ui.value < 20)  // corrected
                    return false;
                else
                    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );

            }
      });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

Comment: Anytime!! Happy coding.. :)